# Behavioural Biometric in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display a shape and ask user to move across the boundary of that shape and then take the sensors data for registration of the user. Since i am a beginner in android can anyone help me with the same.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basics, download android studio and follow a tutorial to create a image view.

Then, load your image and convert it to a bitmap (make sure the image is not too big!). Loop through all pixels and the neighbours of it. Calculate the difference in color from the pixel relative to the neighbours if it's high it's likely a edge.

Now you know the edges, track the position of the user cursor or finger and check if the absolute x,y corresponds with the found edges.

But trust me, it's not this easy, you will encounter a lot of problems, and it will consume a lot of commitment. If you whould like this challenge, find tutorials, a lot of tutorials ;)